# IRC Bot Python | Identify Nickname

Tags: python, sockets, bots, irc, identify

Here is my trouble: The Bot loads the IRC information fine, but when its suppose to Identify itself, he doesn't.

The following is the relevant part of the code. I guess the problem is on line 9 but I can't figure out why.

```
import socket

server = #ServerName
channel = #ChannelName
botnick = #BotName
password = #Password (string)

def connect(channel, password): # This function is used on connect.
  ircsock.send("PRIVMSG" + " :NICKSERV Identify " + password +"\n") #Problem Here
  ircsock.send("JOIN "+ channel +"\n")

ircsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ircsock.connect((server, 6667)) # Here we connect to the server using the port 6667
ircsock.send("USER "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +":Just testing .\n") # user authentication
ircsock.send("NICK "+ botnick +"\n")

connect(channel, password) #Join the channel and identify the nick using the functions we previously defined
```

Thanks in advance.

**Solution:**
By setting the connect function as posted, it is the first thing to be called
Then the server was trying to connect before having USER / NICK.

```
    def create_connection():
    global ircsock
    ircsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ircsock.connect((server, 6667)) # Here we connect to the server using the port 6667
    ircsock.send("USER "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +":This bot is a result of GStones mastery .\n") # user authentication
    ircsock.send("NICK "+ botnick +"\n") # here we actually assign the nick to the bot
    time.sleep(5)
    connect(channel, password) # Join the channel and identify the nick using the functions we previously defined

create_connection()
```

Thanks *i\OFF*

Comment: ircsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Comment: The bot enters into the irc server but misses to execute the connect function so the NickServ ask for identify command:
"NOTICE Botman :This nickname is registered. Please choose a different nickname, or identify via /msg NickServ identify <password>"

Comment: Also try using a different botnick.

Answer (score 3):

You have not created a socket, so the connection will not be established.

`ircsock = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` creates a socket.

Also, you need to connect to the server, before using `ircsock.send()`.

`ircsock.connect ((server, serverPort))` connects to the server.
This example should work:

```
import socket

server = #ServerName
serverPort = #Server Port number
channel = #ChannelName
botnick = #BotName
password = #Password (string)

def connect(channel, password): # This function is used on connect.
  ircsock = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  ircsock.connect ((server, serverPort))
  ircsock.send("USER "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +":Just testing .\n") # user authentication
  ircsock.send("NICK "+ botnick +"\n")
  ircsock.send("PRIVMSG" + " NICKSERV :identify " + password +"\n") #Problem Here
  ircsock.send("JOIN "+ channel +"\n")

connect(channel, password) #Join the channel and identify the nick using the functions we previously defined
```

Comment: I had omitted that part of code.
I already edited the post with the connection to the socket.
But thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Ok, I was not aware of that because in the original post you didn't mention that part of the code. Please try the answer from sideshowbarker & let us know if it worked?

Comment: My apologies.
Already tried. Unfortunately it failed.
The code runs without error, and the bot accesses the irc but does not identify the nick

Comment: Try using the same code for some free IRC chat server & channel instead. It might be that the code is working fine but the IRC server or channel settings are blocking the bot. Just a guess.

Comment: It doens't seem so because the bot executes other functions like ping and a simple hello interaction.
In any case I will try it.